# Removing and Reloading collection view from UICollectionViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My each `UICollectionViewCell` class have a delete button:

```
@IBAction func hideSingleCampaign(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Once tapped, cell disappears, and `UICollectionView` is left with empty space. I have no `UICollectionView` reference from cell class so I can't use `collectionView.reloadData()`

How am I supposed to shift other cells up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the object from the array that you are using with your `CollectionViewDataSource` method instead of deleting `cell`, So first of all declare action of `Button` inside `CollectionViewCell`, so that add action of button in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell {
    var  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionCell
    cell.delBtn.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.delBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onDeletTapped(_:)),
             forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Add this method `onDeletTapped` on your `ViewController`

```
func onDeletTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let index = sender.tag
    yourArray.removeAtIndex(index)
    self.collectinView.reloadData()
}
```